# How can I use a French verb substantival? - For example to formulate a title?

Tags: traduction, mode-grammatical

In English: to live - living (Living on Earth): to cook - cooking (Title: Cooking of vegetables). I am specially interested in a substantival  form for "Speaking"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In French, the infinitive is the substantivated form of a verb so you can say:

> Living on earch → *Vivre sur Terre.*
>
> Cooking of vegetables → *Cuisiner les légumes.*
>
> Speaking Spanish → *Parler l'espagnol.*

You might also use regular nouns:

> *La vie sur terre.*
>
> *La cuisine des légumes.*
>
> *La langue (parlée) espagnole*

in the latter case, *langue* is often omitted:

> *L'espagnol*.

Some infinitives can be used as real substantives, which is the case of *parler* so a (rarer) alternative is:

> *Le parler espagnol*.

There is also the very outdated *[parlure](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parlure)*:

> *La parlure espagnole*.